# ¿Cómo puedo limitar la entrada de carácteres de varios entry en Python (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo una aplicación que toma los datos enteros de 4 entradas distintas y las calcula, sin embargo, necesito que estas entradas admitan solo 2 números, excepto  la que muestra el resultado. Ejemplo del código:

```
from tkinter import Label, Entry, Button, Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x250')
root.title('Calcular nota final por cortes')

def fnCalcular():
   n1 = corte1.get()
   n2 = corte2.get()
   n3 = corte3.get()
   n4 = corte4.get()

   r = (int(n1) + int(n2) + int(n3) + int(n4)) / 4
   resultado.delete(0, 'end')
   resultado.insert(0, r)

corte1_label = Label(root, text='1er corte:')
corte1_label.pack()
corte1 = Entry(root)
corte1.pack()

corte2_label = Label(root, text='2do corte:')
corte2_label.pack()
corte2 = Entry(root)
corte2.pack()

corte3_label = Label(root, text='3er corte:')
corte3_label.pack()
corte3 = Entry(root)
corte3.pack()

corte4_label = Label(root, text='4to corte:')
corte4_label.pack()
corte4 = Entry(root)
corte4.pack()

calcular_boton = Button(root, text='Calcular', command = fnCalcular)
calcular_boton.pack()

resultado = Entry(root)
resultado.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, se los agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: No entiendo a que te referís con "que admita solo dos numeros". Podrías explayar sobre eso por favor?

Comment: Me explico, que el usuario no pueda colocar más de 2 números en cada entry (excepto en el del resultado), porque ese sistema de notas va de 0 a 20.

Comment: Ahhh, ya entendí, entonces con numero te refieres a cifra. Para lograr eso, tendrías que usar un [validador](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/validar-el-contenido-de-una-caja-de-texto-en-tkinter/). A mi me gusta mezclarlo con [regex](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html), pero en tu caso no será necesario.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto cuenta como respuesta pero a lo mejor podrías poner una condición de que si los números puestos en los entry son mayores de 20, de mensaje de error.

```
if corte1_label <= 20:
   #Aquí escribirías todo lo que quieres que haga el programa.
```

tambíen puedes utilizar and para que se cumpla en todos los entry, avísame si no funciona.

Comment: iría justo despues de declarar n4